# Flex Accessing Node in an ArrayCollection Based on a Variable's Value

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

I need some help accessing a value in my arrayCollection in Flex 3.

var f:String;

I need to access the photoFilePath where series = f. So if f=2, then I need /pics/my2.png

So, pseudo code: myAc.(series="f").photoFilePath

```
<mx:ArrayCollection id="myAC">
    <mx:Object label="Label 1" series="1" photoFilePath="/pics/my1.png" pageTitle="First"/>
    <mx:Object label="Label 2" series="2" photoFilePath="/pics/my2.png" pageTitle="Second"/>
</mx:ArrayCollection>
```

Any suggestions.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var n:int = myAC.length;
var f:String;
for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var item:Object = myAC.getItemAt(i);
    if (item.series == f)
    {
        trace(item.photoFilePath);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thanks so much. That worked perfectly. I learned something new.